# Change CSS color from select list option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change css based on a select list options, what am I doing wrong?
Help is much appreciated! (I can't change the HTML)

Many thanks.

Erwin

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  var color = $("#5f01264e722ae").val();
  $("#sw_poster_text2").css("background", color);
});
```

```css
.sw_poster_text2 {
  margin: 30px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-field-input">

  <select data-is-required="" data-field-id="5f01264e722ae" name="wapf[field_5f01264e722ae]" class="wapf-input">
    <option value="">choose an option</option>
    <option value="0z489" data-wapf-label="black">black </option>
    <option value="wu4xz" data-wapf-label="brown">brown </option>
    <option value="5k848" data-wapf-label="blue">blue </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sw_poster_text2">My name</div>
```

Comment: your select has no id attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label')` to get the value of the select and use `.` instead of `#` to select elements with a particular class.

```
var color = $(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label')
$(".sw_poster_text2").css("background", color);
```

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  var color = $(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label')
$(".sw_poster_text2").css("background", color);
});
```

```css
.sw_poster_text2 {
  margin: 30px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-field-input">

  <select data-is-required="" data-field-id="5f01264e722ae" name="wapf[field_5f01264e722ae]" class="wapf-input">
    <option value="">choose an option</option>
    <option value="0z489" data-wapf-label="black">black </option>
    <option value="wu4xz" data-wapf-label="brown">brown </option>
    <option value="5k848" data-wapf-label="blue">blue </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sw_poster_text2">My name</div>
```

Comment: The color values OP got are incorrect and will not work. Just FYI.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Note that I am getting a data attribute, not the value.

Comment: Make sense the op has some color as values. So i am guessing that's what he refers to as colors.

Comment: @hev1

Thank you very much, this is working!

One more question for newbie me, how do I insert it into a working script inside my .php file?

I have the below script to display a live text on an image, now I want the text to change color based on the other selection field mentioned earlier.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   
  var fieldId = "5f0124e773aa8"; 
  var defaultText = "My name"; 
   
  if(!jQuery('input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]').length)
    return;
    
  var $el = jQuery('<div class="sw_poster_text2">').html(defaultText);
  $el.appendTo(jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images'));
   
  jQuery(document).on('change keyup','input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]',function(){
   var v = jQuery(this).val() || defaultText;
   jQuery('.sw_poster_text2').html(v);
    
  }).trigger('change');
 });

Comment: Just place the change event listener inside the document ready callback.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted. Can you please show me how? https://jsfiddle.net/e6oxnspy/1/

Comment: @hev1, so simple :) the code works nicely in jsfiddle ~ thanks, however it is breaking the image on which I would like to print and the options on my site: https://www.horseglamour.com/product/pagony-concours-zadeldek/. I am trying to accomplish using the field "Embroidery color" to change the color of "my name" Any idea?

Comment: @epostema You might want to make a minimal reproducible example and ask a new question in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Your option value not is a valid color, you need set a valid color to after set in your style try this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var color = $("#5f01264e722ae").val();
  $("#sw_poster_text2").css("background", color);
});
```

```
.sw_poster_text2 {
  margin: 30px;
  background: white;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-field-input">

  <select data-is-required="" data-field-id="5f01264e722ae" name="wapf[field_5f01264e722ae]" class="wapf-input">
    <option value="">choose an option</option>
    <option value="black" data-wapf-label="black">black</option>
    <option value="brown" data-wapf-label="brown">brown</option>
    <option value="blue" data-wapf-label="blue">blue</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sw_poster_text2">My name</div>
```

Comment: This does not work at the OP wanted. You answer is not working. Please review your answer.